# How to extract docker image name from sha

Tags: docker

I am trying to resolve docker image name using sha256 value. Does docker already provides an API to do that? Or do I need to write something myself?

As per @Zgurskyi suggestion, I tried using inspect, somehow it gives me error:

```
# docker images --digests
REPOSITORY                               TAG                 DIGEST                                                                    IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
alpine                                   3.4                 sha256:b733d4a32c4da6a00a84df2ca32791bb03df95400243648d8c539e7b4cce329c   b7c5ffe56db7        7 weeks ago         4.82MB

# docker image inspect b733d4a32c4da6a00a84df2ca32791bb03df95400243648d8c539e7b4cce329c
[]
Error: No such image: b733d4a32c4da6a00a84df2ca32791bb03df95400243648d8c539e7b4cce329c
```

TIA.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`inspect`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/image_inspect/) command and `RepoTags` is probably info you need:

```
docker image inspect <sha256>
```

If you have `jq` installed, then just use the following:

```
docker image inspect <sha256> | jq .[0].RepoTags
```

Comment: Thanks.I tried that. It gives me error that image not found. I have updated the findings in the question. Should I be using any other sha?

Comment: @Pensu You can just use the IMAGE ID (b7c5ffe56db7 in your example). So, try `docker image inspect b7c5ffe56db7`.

Comment: In my tests this only seems to work if the image was actually pulled using a tag. If you pull an image by SHA it has no tags (unless you later pull it by tag, in which case the RepoTags field gets updated).

Answer (score 2):

To resolve the digest, you also need the repository name. E.g.:

```
docker inspect alpine@sha256:b733d4a32c4da6a00a84df2ca32791bb03df95400243648d8c539e7b4cce329c
```

You can also use docker formatting instead of relying on `jq` which may not always be installed (though it really should be):

```
# to list the first RepoTag, this can fail if the RepoTags list is empty (locally built image):
$ docker image inspect "${repo}@${sha256}" --format '{{index .RepoTags 0}}'

# to list all RepoTags with a space separator:
$ docker image inspect "${repo}@${sha256}" --format '{{range $v := .RepoTags}}{{$v}} {{end}}'
```